# SXA Search results Load more control

Tags: sxa, content-search

I am adding Search Results with Load More renderings. I need to display a number of items loaded with the total number of items returned from search API.

- Is there a way to get this info in SXA?

I am using SXA 1.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To display a total number of results use Results Count rendering:

[image]

To show a number of items loaded by hitting Load More button you would need to add some custom logic (modify Results Count rendering or create a new one). Each time when you hit the button and the results are loaded the following event is triggered. Here is how you could attach for this event:

```
XA.component.search.vent.on("results-loaded", function (results) {
    //you custom logic here
});
```