# Load more feature with page list in sxa

Tags: sxa

Does SXA out of box component PageList support load more feature? There is Page size field in PageList but that is use to return number of results as specified. Search Load more component also does not work with page list. Is there any way to implement load more with Pagelist?

Comment: No, Page List doesn't have such feature. Use Search Results for such functionality.

Comment: Agreed with @DawidRutkowski , You can always create rendering variants for search result and hide your search box to make it look like a page list.

Comment: If I need to use search result then do I need to create scope for each listing page? For example. Product category page will list down all the products created under that and there will mane category pages . So will same search scope will work here?

Comment: Whilst its not a "load more" feature - you could pair a PageList component with a pagination control.   I also found - https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/12252/sxa-search-results-load-more-control but it might be older version and no longer relevant